# Disable listview items with selector and isEnabled()

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter

**Scope**: 
- using overriden ArrayAdapter;
- using selector;
- using isEnabled for disabling items.

**Aim**:
- disable some list items and load disabled state view via selector.

**Problem**:
- everything works (custom view, selector for unfocused, focuesd and pressed states) but disabled items don't use selector for disabled state.

**Investigating**: when I use isEnabled for disabling some items in listview Hierarchy Viewer shows that disabled items are unfocusable, unclickable but(!) enabled.

Is it a **bug** or something is missing?

P.S. actually, docs say that isEnabled doesn't do setEnabled(false) for list item, it makes it a divider(?) object.
P.P.S I also tried to use if-statement to set my View (in getView) as isEnabled(false). But it works only for focused items?

My Selector looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Disabled -->
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:textColor="@color/greyDark"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_disabled" />
    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" />
    <!-- Focused -->
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_focused" />
    <!-- Default -->
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_unfocused" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hack:** 
use getView to check disabled item logic and inflate view with another layout. isEnabled is still usefull.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row;

    if (mListItem[position].isEnabled() == false) row = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.list_row_disabled, null);
    else {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        // set right extensible icon
        if (mListItem[position].getType()) {
            ImageView ic_arrow = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_row_arrow);
            ic_arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right);
        }
    }
    // set left icon
    ImageView ic_item = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_row_icon);
    ic_item.setImageResource(mListItem[position].getIcon());
    // blend icon if item is disabled
    if (mListItem[position].isEnabled() == false) 
        ic_item.setColorFilter(0x99D0D0D0,Mode.SRC_ATOP); // make icons look grayer 

    // set title text
    TextView txvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
    txvTitle.setText(mListItem[position].getTitle());

    return row;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return mListItem[position].isEnabled();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The function isEnabled() in the adapter only makes item unfocusable and unclickable.
You need to call `view.setEnabled()` at the end of `adapter.getView()` to make your selector functional.

Also, for a parent view to pass enable state to its descendants, you need to specify the attribute `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to the child views in your xml file.

Comment: Note to future readers: don't do what I did and assume I only needed the first part because I didn't have nested layouts in my XML layout file!