# Android ListView with active and inactive entries

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I need a listview that has several clickable entries. However, some of them are inactive until an asynctask releases them. How should I best do this? First I thought of having a seperate ArrayList with booleans but that seems to be somehow cheap. Is there a way to expand the StableArrayAdapter?

This is my current adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: I just found this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744863/disable-listview-items-with-selector-and-isenabled

Answer (score 1):

Override [`isEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)) in your adapter. You can return false for the items that should not be clickable at first. Then when your AsyncTask completes, in `onPostExecute()` you can call some other method you define on your adapter to enable the items, from which point on your `isEnabled()` implementation should return true for those items.

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your adapter

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled (int position) {
    // Add your logic here. Return true for the items you 
    //want to be enable and false for those you want disable.
}
```

**Usage (From android documentation):** Returns true if the item at the specified position is not a separator. (A separator is a non-selectable, non-clickable item). The result is unspecified if position is invalid. An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException should be thrown in that case for fast failure.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement. you can use SparseBooleanArrays to represent the state of each list item whether it has to be active/ inactive.
checkout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model class for the staus of each item in your list and then manipulate it in your getView . Like Below ..

```
public class StatusBean{

private boolean isNameActive;
private boolean isOtherFieldActive;

public String isnameActive() {
    return isNameActive;
}
public void setNameActive(boolean isNameActive) {
    this.isNameActive=isNameActive;
}
public boolean isOtherFieldActive;() {
    return isOtherFieldActive;
}
public void setOtherFieldActive;(boolean bool) {
    this.isOtherFieldActive = isOtherFieldActive;
}
```

}

And then set these fields to active state in when your asyncTask is finished. And call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

There you are done! let me know if you face any problem in it